# How do I declare a block that returns a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I keep trying to create a block that will return a UIView after it fetches it from the background. I got the fetch from the background part, but I am having trouble setting up the block. This code works, but I want a block that can be called from another file. Thanks in advance.

I can't call launchAd for viewDidLoad, and nothing works.

```
typedef void (^launchAd)(UIView *);
-(void)launchAd:(void (^)(UIView *ad))block
{

}
```

Comment: Your code is too abstract and does not return any UIView. Please show your _real_ code and explain what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can try something like below:

```
//class file 1:     
+ (void) doYourStuff:(void (^)(UIView* returnedView))successBlock {
    successBlock(returnedView);
}

//class file 2: 
[class1 doYourStuff:success:^(UIView* returnedView) {
    //do whatever you want with the returned data
}];
```

If you want to add failure block to return failure scenarios:

```
+ (void) doYourStuff:(void (^)(UIView* returnedView))successBlock
           failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failureBlock {
           if (getView)
            successBlock(returnedView);
           else 
            failureBlock(error);
}
```

Comment: thanks this is awesome! One question, how do I tell the do YourStuff method that the method succeeded. So lets say I made the UIView. How do I pass that UIView and announce the success?

Comment: @Team6Labs I have modified the answer include failure case. The success block contains the success case and failure block contains failure case

Comment: By convention inObjective-C only methods that return a value by reference start with "get". Typically the method name would be something like: `memberSuccess:failure:`.

Comment: @Zaph thanks for reminding of coding style, modified, appreciate it